# SerialPortIO Electron

Tags: npm, serial-port, electron

I am trying to run a simple electron app to read and write values from the port COM4, I already downloaded and properly installed node.js and serialport io this is the way i did it:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
# Go into the repository
$ cd electron-quick-start
# Install the dependencies and run
$ npm install && npm start
```

Once that is done. Install serialport library.

```
$ npm install --save serialport 
$ npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

Rebuild Electron

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
$ npm rebuild
```

This is my index.html

```
        var SerialPort = require('serialport');
        const Readline = serialPort.parsers.Readline;

        //initialize serialport with 115200 baudrate.
        var sp = new serialPort('COM4', {
            baudRate: 115200,
        });

        function writeonSer(data){
            //Write the data to serial port.
            sp.write( data, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
                }
                console.log('message written');
            });

        }
    </script>
    <script>
        // You can also require other files to run in this process
        require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
```

And finanlly i am getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: The module '\\?\C:\Users\atorres\Desktop\SerialPort\electron-quick-start\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 73. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:155)
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:155)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:828)
    at Object.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:155)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:155)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16)
    at bindings (C:\Users\atorres\Des…ngs\bindings.js:112)
```

Please Help! Thanks.

Comment: is your node.js up to date?

Comment: yes i did npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: https://github.com/serialport/electron-serialport have you looked at this boilerplate? I have no idea where you are with your project. But if you wanted to save yourself some time you could use this as a starting point. The only issue I had setting it up was some write/execute permissions on one or two directories.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get github.com/serialport/electron-serialport working in a windows environment by installing Visual Studio C++ development package. I had a similar error to what you had previously. Specifically it required MSVS build tools. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ the tools can be had here :)

I also attempted using NVM-Windows and running the module version specified in the SerialPort/Bindings directory files. This actually did not work, so maybe the error is reporting incorrectly? At any rate, hope this helps.